# Skip rows when reading data from file using numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, io

I have a data set in a file as shown below

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
```

I would like to extract only rows which contain `'A'`. How do I do that with `numpy.genfromtxt`? Is there any other function available in numpy that helps me do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy.genfromtxt` accepts generators, so you can chain `genfromtext` and `ifilter`:

```
from itertools import ifilter
with open(fname, 'rb') as inp:
     filtered_inp = ifilter(lambda x: x.startswith('A'), inp)
     a = np.genfromtxt(filtered_inp)
```

Comment: Thank you @alko :) This should be a tad bit faster than reading all data from a file. I hope numpy comes up with a direct implementation in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can read the whole file and filter afterwards using fancy indexing:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype=str)

check = (a[:,0]=='A')
a = a[check]
```

Answer (score 1):

I too have wanted this feature, but it does not exist.  So for now you should probably just load the whole file as a matrix, then use fancy indexing to subset it, or delete the parts you don't want, etc.  If the number of rows you actually want is very small and the total size is very large, you might even be better off just iterating over the lines in the regular Python way.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Well the number of rows i want are pretty large. I am loading the entire file currently.

Comment: Then what you have now is probably as good as it gets until someone writes a patch for NumPy.